# I'm having trouble with my event propagation function in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, stoppropagation

I have a master function that I have to disable my event propagation:

```
project.disabledEventPropagation = function (e) {
    if (!e)
        e = window.event;

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    }
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

I call this function in my javascript files like this:

```
project.disabledEventPropagation();
```

this works great in chrome and in internet explorer but it doesn't work in firefox. I tried debugging (using firebug) and I keep getting an saying that 'e' is undefined. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Well, Firefox doesn't put the `event` object in global scope (hence the error), so you have to pass it to the function/method. I mean, you wrote the function, so must know how it works, don't you?

Comment: When you call it you don't pass the `e` argument in. Are you calling it from within an event handler? (Also you don't have a cross-browser implementation of `preventDefault()`, but in any case why do you even have `preventDefault()` in a function with a name `disabledEventPropagation()`?)

Comment: so you guys mean I would actually need to pass in my event when calling my global function like this: project.disabledEventPropagation(event);

Comment: and no, I'm not calling it from an event handler. I have an event handler which calls a function. In this function I call my global one that I listed

Comment: Well, you have to pass down the event object somehow.

Comment: You are calling it indirectly from your event handler, via this other function, so as Felix says you have to pass the event object through. (And, further to my previous comment, `event.returnValue = false;` is the old-IE way of preventing the default behaviour.)

Comment: alright, I got it. passing the event down did the trick. thanks